# How to clear or delete cache of a specific template/view?

Tags: ember.js

Is there anyway to flush a specific template/view from the cache? I tried following but no luck

```
delete APP.__container__.cache.dict['template:main']
delete APP.__container__.lookup('template:main')
APP.__container__.unregister('template:main')
APP.__container__.cache.remove('template:main')
APP.__container__.factoryCache.remove('template:main')
```

Why do i need this?
I have a simple login logout auth based on [this link](http://log.simplabs.com/post/53016599611/authentication-in-ember-js). But even when i logout, the view is still rendered. if i login again with other account details, i am getting older logged view even though the model is updated.

Comment: `After I wrote this I found out that it’s actually not the best approach to implement authentication in Ember.js… There are some things missing and some other things can be done in a much simpler way.` Maybe try following the updated tutorial or using the plugin provided? http://log.simplabs.com/post/57702291669/better-authentication-in-ember-js

Comment: ok..didn't check updated part...